# jquery executing menu loading before the page loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have an issue with the menu that I have. It's done in jquery and every time I refresh the page I can see all the levels of the menu, and then it seems like jquery starts working, and menu is formatted to look nice. I was wondering if there is a way to load that jquery before it appears on the screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say what the best solution is without seeing any code. But why don't you `.hide()` the menu before it generates, then `.show()` it when it's complete?

Comment: code samples? try checking with $(document).ready or $(window).ready

Comment: @mblase75, that would also display the elements pre-JQuery, as the JQuery library will load intermittently with the DOM. So you will need to hide the element in CSS and then show it when the JQuery library loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the menu display to none. Then when the page loads use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu").whatEverPlugin().show();
});
```

Comment: I have noticed a lot of plugins will set the display of their elements as part of their styling. So first try just setting `display: none;` on the main element you are applying the plugin to.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best solution for this type of issue is to hide the html elements using css (display:none) in your stylesheet. jQuery works by overriding those css attributes on mouse events, so the menu should still function correctly even if the items are hidden initially.

Answer (score 1):

When you first start building the menu you could set it to be hidden, then as the last step make it visible.